# Sass can't be run unless as superuser Linux Mint

Tags: ruby, linux, sass, sudo, su

I'm using Linux Mint 16 cinnamon, and I've lately installed Sass.
Oddly, I can't use Sass unless I'm superuser, which isn't great...

As example, If I type `sass -v` in the terminal as SU, I have the right Sass version displayed. If I'm not SU, I have this message:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find sass (>= 0) amongst [bundler-1.5.3, bundler-unload-1.0.2, executable-hooks-1.3.1, gem-wrappers-1.2.4, rubygems-bundler-1.4.2, rvm-1.11.3.9] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/sass:22:in `<main>'
```

The same thing happens when I want to start using it. I have to be SU.
I've already uninstalled/reinstalled Sass, but that doesn't work.

Any tip, please?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Ruby - Unable to create rails application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587594/unable-to-create-rails-application-due-to-errors).  Make sure railties is installed: `gem install railties`.

Comment: I did this, but that still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You may first want to run `gem env` to see the difference between what it returns when you are that particular user and what it returns when you are superuser. Of all the results, "GEM PATHS" would be something most important here.

And then when you are the user, you can sort of forcefully set $GEM_HOME (your default gem location) and $GEM_PATH (your available gem locations) to the location the superuser was looking at. It should be something like this:

```
export GEM_HOME=/where/superuser/was/looking/at
export GEM_PATH=/where/superuser/was/looking/at
```

Just one of the possible solutions you can try. It would be nice if we could know how you installed your ruby.

Comment: I followed some steps to install Sass from a blog, But well, as It didn't work correctly I did some others things, but honestly I can't remember what exactly. I messed up everything.About what you asked to me. I did it, and It seems as SU i have another version than as simple user. Here is a screenshot as a SU http://users.skynet.be/fa341830/SU_SASS.png another whitout being SU.http://users.skynet.be/fa341830/NU_SASS.png  About Path, I don't understand what I have to do,I've been using Linux for 2 days.If you could help me.